# Lightbox2 | Horizontal images minimized

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

I have a problem with lightbox2: in the same page, higher than wide images are displayed correctly when cliked, but the wider than the tall ones are minimized. Would someone have a solution?

Thanks!

The page is visible here: https://fabiengranjon.eu/photographies/

And here is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/wp-content/js/lightbox/css/lightbox.min.css">
<h2>C'est (très) en vrac&nbsp;!</h2>
<h5>NYC, Rennes, Londres, Cancale, Lisbonne, Le Cotentin, Paris, Goux, Amsterdam, Sorano, Saint-Malo, Montréal, Istanbul, Portbou, Arles, etc.</h5>
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32350058_10213293354783031_3926162921058467840_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2998" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32350058_10213293354783031_3926162921058467840_o-300x199.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="199"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32399288_10213293351302944_8510532801454407680_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2999" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32399288_10213293351302944_8510532801454407680_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32349753_10213293349102889_7229431442462212096_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2997" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32349753_10213293349102889_7229431442462212096_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32349078_10213293351982961_1688827290210795520_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2996" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32349078_10213293351982961_1688827290210795520_o-300x199.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="199"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32327693_10213293353623002_6659132495054766080_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2995" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32327693_10213293353623002_6659132495054766080_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32313875_10213293353142990_2050811342985625600_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2994" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32313875_10213293353142990_2050811342985625600_o-300x199.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="199"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32313301_10213293352342970_3609728473926467584_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2993" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32313301_10213293352342970_3609728473926467584_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32313268_10213293354343020_2583599648052609024_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2992" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32313268_10213293354343020_2583599648052609024_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32313239_10213293350582926_2253638278731268096_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2991" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32313239_10213293350582926_2253638278731268096_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32290864_10213293352222967_686614826515955712_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2990" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32290864_10213293352222967_686614826515955712_o-300x199.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="199"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32286598_10213293349622902_5610853436208709632_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2989" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32286598_10213293349622902_5610853436208709632_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32283807_10213293350542925_6258268439811457024_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2988" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32283807_10213293350542925_6258268439811457024_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32264180_10213293352542975_8332722508314705920_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2987" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/32264180_10213293352542975_8332722508314705920_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13937993_10208074331070700_88344000744246522_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2986" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13937993_10208074331070700_88344000744246522_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13937982_10208074362431484_3858773296779722414_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2985" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13937982_10208074362431484_3858773296779722414_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13925966_10208074363071500_9195310606966083837_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2984" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13925966_10208074363071500_9195310606966083837_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13925602_10208074333750767_762800376347890794_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2983" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13925602_10208074333750767_762800376347890794_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13923691_10208074367991623_6533130278133574977_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2982" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13923691_10208074367991623_6533130278133574977_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13920396_10208074336430834_8377681038634171945_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2981" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13920396_10208074336430834_8377681038634171945_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13913968_10208074330830694_5680934256552376769_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2980" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13913968_10208074330830694_5680934256552376769_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13668704_10208074344391033_2376846719903442422_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2979" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13668704_10208074344391033_2376846719903442422_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13662202_10208074335350807_6040311643828343594_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2978" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13662202_10208074335350807_6040311643828343594_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13653477_10208074331710716_8793880860774293438_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2977" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/13653477_10208074331710716_8793880860774293438_o-199x300.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/12779205_10206885401988216_4265500163307200419_o.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2976" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/12779205_10206885401988216_4265500163307200419_o-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/11188230_10204917185624037_5914574035601282326_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2975" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/11188230_10204917185624037_5914574035601282326_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/11156305_10204917186784066_8732496800111152691_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2974" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/11156305_10204917186784066_8732496800111152691_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/11115599_10204917184624012_5186227445729535554_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2973" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/11115599_10204917184624012_5186227445729535554_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/11008543_10204917182143950_3985294221319220750_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2972" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/11008543_10204917182143950_3985294221319220750_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10641272_10204917182823967_8958287521015797611_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2971" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10641272_10204917182823967_8958287521015797611_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093342008409_1330_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2970" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093342008409_1330_n-240x300.jpg" alt="" width="240" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341968408_789_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2969" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341968408_789_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341128387_9581_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2968" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341128387_9581_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341088386_8996_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2967" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341088386_8996_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341048385_8385_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2966" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341048385_8385_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341008384_7813_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2965" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093341008384_7813_n-300x267.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="267"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093335848255_9946_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2964" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093335848255_9946_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093335808254_9381_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2963" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10400736_1093335808254_9381_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10370454_10202584303503442_3834517868031262520_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2962" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10370454_10202584303503442_3834517868031262520_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10363781_10202584300783374_4849001022641501147_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2961" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10363781_10202584300783374_4849001022641501147_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10320587_10202584302383414_7644699844920519743_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2960" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10320587_10202584302383414_7644699844920519743_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10294348_10202584302903427_5416093495756050636_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2959" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10294348_10202584302903427_5416093495756050636_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10289797_10202584304383464_8320358882470980161_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2958" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10289797_10202584304383464_8320358882470980161_n-225x300.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="300"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/10273752_10202584304823475_8834331820865903272_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;">

[…]

<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2777" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/1778_1066897307308_442_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a> <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/1778_1066897267307_9900_n.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" style="color:#ddd;text-decoration:none;"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-2776" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/1778_1066897267307_9900_n-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225"></a>

<script src="/wp-content/js/lightbox/lightbox.js"><br />
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code?

Comment: I added it to the question. Sorry for this long response time.